# How to write code that optimizes this schedule alignment

Tags: optimization, matching, schedule

I have a list of names and a bunch of "yes" or "no" entries that indicate if a person is available at a certain time. It looks like this:

```
names = ['Jim Green',
  'Yes',
  'Yes',
  'Yes',
  'No',
  'Yes',
  'Yes',
  'Yes',
  'Yes',
  'No',
  'Yes',
  'No',
  'No',
  'Yes',
  'Yes',
  'No',
  'Yes',
  'No',
  'No',
  'No',
  'Yes',
  'Yes'],
 ['Tom Brown',
  'No',
  'Yes',
  'Yes',
  'Yes',
  'Yes',
  'No',
  'Yes',
  'No',
  'Yes',
  'No',
  'Yes',
  'No',
  'No',
  'Yes',
  'No',
  'No',
  'No',
  'Yes',
  'No',
  'Yes',
  'No'],
 ['Silly Guy',
  'Yes',
  'Yes',
  'No',
  'No',
  'No',
  'Yes',
  'No',
  'No',
  'Yes',
  'Yes',
  'Yes',
  'No',
  'Yes',
  'No',
  'Yes',
  'Yes',
  'Yes',
  'Yes',
  'Yes',
  'Yes',
  'Yes']]
```

This goes on for 13 entries. From this, I managed to create a list of lists that shows how many "yes" and "no" entries matchup from person to person. It looks like this:

```
counter_list = [[22, 4, 9, 9, 10, 15, 11, 16, 9, 10, 9, 10, 11],
 [4, 22, 10, 12, 9, 8, 10, 9, 16, 7, 14, 9, 10],
 [9, 10, 22, 11, 10, 11, 11, 10, 9, 12, 7, 8, 9],
 [9, 12, 11, 22, 12, 13, 9, 10, 9, 14, 9, 10, 5],
 [10, 9, 10, 12, 22, 10, 10, 7, 6, 11, 10, 11, 6],
 [15, 8, 11, 13, 10, 22, 7, 14, 9, 10, 9, 10, 7],
 [11, 10, 11, 9, 10, 7, 22, 10, 11, 14, 11, 6, 11],
 [16, 9, 10, 10, 7, 14, 10, 22, 12, 7, 10, 11, 10],
 [9, 16, 9, 9, 6, 9, 11, 12, 22, 6, 11, 8, 13],
 [10, 7, 12, 14, 11, 10, 14, 7, 6, 22, 8, 9, 10],
 [9, 14, 7, 9, 10, 9, 11, 10, 11, 8, 22, 10, 11],
 [10, 9, 8, 10, 11, 10, 6, 11, 8, 9, 10, 22, 10],
 [11, 10, 9, 5, 6, 7, 11, 10, 13, 10, 11, 10, 22]]
```

The "22" entry in each list demonstrates that an individual has complete matching availability times with them self. A higher number means a person has a closer schedule to the corresponding entry. What I want to do is write a program that takes something like the list above and creates groups of 4 people who have schedules that roughly lineup.

I simply have no idea where to begin in trying to do this. Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: depends on what is more valuable - eg: most matches, most consecutive matches, etc.

Comment: Ideally you would store the Yes/No list in a 32bit integer (and use the bits for Yes/No). Then you can just `AND` those integers and count the resulting set bits with popcount.